# Is the use of dynamic considered a bad practice?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection

In C#, someone can do:

```
MyClass myInstance        = new MyClass();
dynamic mydynamicInstance = myInstance;
```

And then, invoke a method, like:

```
//This method takes a MyClass argument and does something.
Caller.InvokeMethod(myDynamicInstance);
```

Now, this will lead to determination of the myInstance type at runtime,
and, if it is valid, the `Caller.InvokeMethod` will be called normally.

Now, my question is if this is considered a bad practice to use `dynamic`, especially in the following cases:

1) `InvokeMethod` instantiates another instance of myDynamicInstance type,
using reflection inside.

2) There is  an abstract base class `MyBaseClass` and a number of subclasses of it, including `MyBaseClass`. If we have a number of overloaded methods of `InvokeMethod` for all of those derived classes, could we use it in order to allow at runtime the type determination and then the proper invocation via method overloading (or late binding on the call of a method of that class)?:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass         {/*...*/}
public class MyClass        : MyBaseClass {/*...*/}
public class MyAnotherClass : MyBaseClass {/*...*/}

MyBaseClass myBaseClassRef = new MyClass();
dynamic myDynamicInstance  = myBaseClassRef;

Caller.InvokeMethod(myDynamicInstance);
```

Comment: Only use dynamic when the alternative is reflection.

Comment: for me subjective: **yes** - it the symptom of me failing to cope with the type-system and it's limitations.

Comment: And even then, sometimes reflection is okay - you get some type guarantees and whatnot.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

## The short answer is YES, it is a bad practice to use dynamic.

**Why?**

**dynamic** keyword refers to type late binding, which means the system will check type only during execution instead of
during compilation. It will then mean that **user**, instead of programmer, **is left to discover the potential error**. The error could be
a MissingMethodException, but it could be also a not intended call to an existing method with a bad behavior.
Imagine a call to a method that ends in computing a bad price or in computing a bad level of oxygen.

Generally speaking, type checking helps to get deterministic computing, and so, when you can, you should use it. Here's a question on [**shortcomings of dynamic**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/135160/shortcomings-of-using-dynamic-types-in-c).

#### However, dynamic can be useful...

- [**Interop with COM** like with Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx)
- **Interop with languages where dynamic types are part of the language** (IronPython, IronRuby) as dynamic was introduced to help porting them to .Net.
- **Can replace reflection complex code with low ceremony, elegant code** (however depending on the case, you still should profile both approaches to check which one is the most appropriate in terms of performance and compile-time checks).

Code base is evolving throughout the application life cycle and even if dynamic seems ok now,
it set a precedent which can implies an increase of dynamic keyword usage by your team. It can lead to increased
maintenance costs (in case the above stated signature evolves, you can notice it too late). Of course, you could
rely on unit tests, non regression human tests and so on. But when you have to choose between human discipline related
quality and automatically checked by computer related quality, choose the later. It's less error prone.

#### In your case...

In your case, it seems you can use the common inheritance scheme (the first one below and the one you mention in your question),
as **`dynamic` won't give you any additional benefit** (it will just cost you more processing power and make you incurring
the risk of future potential bugs).

It depends on whether you can change code of `MyClass` hierarchy and/or `Caller.InvokeMethod`.

#### Let's enumerate

the different possible alternatives to dynamic...

- **Compiled type-checked alternative to dynamic keyword method call:**

The most common is using **interface virtual call** like this instance.InvokeMethod() with inheritance calling the right implementation.

```
public interface IInvoker : { void InvokeMethod(); }
public abstract class MyBaseClass : IInvoker { public abstract void InvokeMethod(); }
public class MyAnotherClass : MyBaseClass { public override void InvokeMethod() { /* Do something */ } }
public class MyClass : MyBaseClass { public override void InvokeMethod() { /* Do something */ } }
```

Another a little less performant is by using **Extension Methods**

```
public static class InvokerEx:
{
    public static void Invoke(this MyAnotherClass c) { /* Do something */ } }
    public static void Invoke(this MyClass c) { /* Do something */ } }
}
```

If there are several "visitors" of MyBaseClass hierarchy, you can use the **Visitor pattern**:

```
public interface IVisitor 
{
    void Visit(this MyAnotherClass c);
    void Visit(this MyClass c);
}

public abstract class MyBaseClass : IInvoker { public abstract void Accept(IVisitor visitor); }
public class MyAnotherClass : MyBaseClass { public override void Accept(IVisitor visitor) { visitor.Visit(this); } }
public class MyClass : MyBaseClass { public override void Accept(IVisitor visitor) { visitor.Visit(this); } }
```

Other variants though not very useful here (**Generic method**) but interesting for the performance comparison:

```
public void InvokeMethod<T>(T instance) where T : IInvoker { return instance.InvokeMethod(); }
```

- **Dynamic alternative to dynamic keyword method call :**

If you need to call a method not known at compile time, I've added below the different techniques you could use and updated the performance results:

**MethodInfo.CreateDelegate**

```
        _method = typeof (T).GetMethod("InvokeMethod");
        _func = (Func<T, int>)_method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, int>));
```

*Note: Cast to Func is needed to avoid call DynamicInvoke (as it is generally slower).*

**DynamicMethod and ILGenerator.Emit**

It actually build the full call from scratch, it's the most flexible but you must have some assembler background to fully appreciate it.

```
        _dynamicMethod = new DynamicMethod("InvokeMethod", typeof (int), new []{typeof(T)}, GetType().Module);
        ILGenerator il = _dynamicMethod.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Call, _method);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        _func = (Func<T, int>) _dynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof (Func<T, int>));
```

**Linq Expression**

It's similar to DynamicMethod, however you don't control the IL generated. Though, it's really more readable.

```
        _method = typeof (T).GetMethod("InvokeMethod");
        var instanceParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T), "instance");
        var call = Expression.Call(instanceParameter, _method);
        _delegate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, int>>(call, instanceParameter).Compile();
        _func = (Func<T, int>) _delegate;
```

**MethodInfo.Invoke**

The last but not the least, the standard known reflection call.
However, even if it's easy to mess with it, don't use it as it's really a bad performer (look at the benchmark results). Prefer CreateDelegate which is really faster.

```
        _method = typeof (T).GetMethod("InvokeMethod");
        return (int)_method.Invoke(instance, _emptyParameters);
```

**Code of the benchmark test can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/stormleoxia/stackoverflow).**

**Benchmark of the different methods** to get an order of magnitude (for 10 Millions of call) *(.NET Framework 4.5)*:

| Method | Elapsed | Calls per ms | Scale |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Class standard call | 00:00:00.0532945 | 188679 | 1 |
| Extension Method | 00:00:00.0637817 | 158730 | 1.19 |
| Generic Method | 00:00:00.0772658 | 129870 | 1.45 |
| Interface virtual | 00:00:00.0778103 | 129870 | 1.45 |
| `MethodInfo.CreateDelegate` | 00:00:00.1131495 | 88495 | 2.13 |
| `DynamicMethod.Emit` | 00:00:00.1152792 | 86956 | 2.17 |
| Visitor `Accept`/`Visit` | 00:00:00.1384779 | 72463 | 2.60 |
| Linq `Expression` | 00:00:00.3158967 | 31746 | 5.94 |
| Keyword `dynamic` | 00:00:00.3805229 | 26315 | 7.17 |
| `MethodInfo.Invoke` | 00:00:05.3104416 | 1883 | 100.19 |

**EDIT:**

So comparing to Visitor pattern, dynamic dispatch is just about **3 times slower**. It can be acceptable for some applications as it can remove cumbersome code. It's always up to you to choose.

Just keep in mind all the drawbacks.

---

**EDIT:** (as an answer to multiple dispatch *benefit*)

Using trendy pattern name like '*multiple dispatch*' and just state that it's cleaner because it uses less code, doesn't make it an added benefit IMHO.
If you want to write trendy code or don't care about type safety and production stability, there are already a lot of language out there offering full feature dynamic typing. I see `dynamic` keyword introduction in C# as a way to close the gap between the strong typed language family and not so strongly typed other languages. It doesn't mean you should change the way you develop and put type checks to trash.

**UPDATE: 2016/11/08** *(.NET Framework 4.6.1)*

Orders of magnitude remain the same (even if some of them have improved a bit):

```
Class standard call: 1
Extension Method call : 1,19
Interface virtual call : 1,46
Generic Method call : 1,54
DynamicMethod.Emit call : 2,07
MethodInfo.CreateDelegate call : 2,13
Visitor Accept/Visit call : 2,64
Linq Expression call : 5,55
Keyword dynamic call : 6,70
MethodInfo Invoke call : 102,96
```

Comment: One more scenario when dynamic is accepted: receive data from source unknown at compilation, for example SQL row (or JSON) when cols are known only at runtime. Alternative implementation is Dictionary<string,Object>. Both are sensitive to "unknown column". Totally agree, out of few scenarion are bad practice

Comment: @JacekCz You always expect some behavior from SQL (or Json) so it could be managed by prototyping them. I'm a big fan of EntityFramework/Nhibernate framework but I understand it may be a tank to kill bees...

Comment: @FabienBondi You are suggesting a method virtual call on hierarchies invocation, but this practically means that the method call will be determined at runtime too, via late binding - using vtables etc internally. It does not seem that benecifial in that case, as both will be determined at runtime, just wondering.....

Comment: @NickL. Method virtual call binding is done a runtime, but the type checking is done at compile time. You can't call a not existing method via standard virtual call, however with dynamic (no type check), you can. Thus with dynamic you increase risks of exception raising.

Comment: Extension methods in C# are static methods as part of an IL 'inlined' compiler trick. Invocation, depending on the function in question of course, doesn't get faster than that. However it does require one additional variable allocation on the calling stack, as opposed to invoking a member method.
@Fab: Very good answer by the way!

Comment: Just an IMO: 'dynamic' should force code to be treated "unsafe" by the compiler (and thus require appropriate unsafe blocks and flags)...

Comment: The performance consideration only comes into it if you are making billions of calls. If your calling a DB or converting json than performance is probably not a concern. It then becomes a strongly typed debate and node and php have done quite well on small code bases.

Answer (score 8):

I don´t fully agree with Fabien that it does not give you additional benefits.
What he is solving with the visitor pattern is called *Multiple dispatch* and dynamic can provide a clean solution to this too. Sure you have to know the implications Fabien mentioned like performance, static type checking...

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
}

public class MyClass : MyBaseClass
{
}
public class MyAnotherClass : MyBaseClass
{
}

public class ClassThatIsUsingBaseClass
{
    public static void PrintName(MyBaseClass baseClass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyBaseClass");
    }

    public static void PrintName(MyClass baseClass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyClass");
    }

    public static void PrintName(MyAnotherClass baseClass)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyAnotherClass");
    }

    public static void PrintNameMultiDispatch(MyBaseClass baseClass)
    {
        ClassThatIsUsingBaseClass.PrintName((dynamic)baseClass);
    }
}
```

And usage is

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MyBaseClass myClass = new MyClass();
    MyBaseClass myAnotherClass = new MyAnotherClass();
    ClassThatIsUsingBaseClass.PrintName(myClass);
    ClassThatIsUsingBaseClass.PrintName(myAnotherClass);
    ClassThatIsUsingBaseClass.PrintNameMultiDispatch(myClass);
    ClassThatIsUsingBaseClass.PrintNameMultiDispatch(myAnotherClass);

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Output is

```
MyBaseClass
MyBaseClass
MyClass
MyAnotherClass
```

Search for "Multiple dispatch" and "C# multiple dispatch" for more infos.

Answer (score 6):

This was answered in 2015, today in 2019 with the patterns we see in JavaScript and Typescript indeed there are good reasons for using dynamic; however, it requires the developer to take caution.

```
    private (Boolean Valid, dynamic Result) ValidatePersonID(int ID)
    {
        var person = _store.Persons.FirstOrDefault(person => person.ID == ID);
        if (person == null)
        {
            string message = $"The person id {ID} does not exist, please try again.";
            return (false, message);
        }
        return (true, person);

    }
```

To use the code above:

```
   var operation = ValidatePersonID(personID);
   if (operation.Valid == false)
     {
        //BadRequest takes a string and C# uses co-variance to make it work.
        return BadRequest(operation.Result);
     }
   //otherwise just cast the type, but requires the cast to always work.
   var pe = (Person)operation.Result;
   ...
```

The return of validity being either True, or False determines the type being returned.  We still pick up strong typing using the cast and or the required input type on BadRequest. We also pick up compile time type checking in that if one of the two returned types ever changes to something other than string, and or person, it won't compile.

I consider this a form of Dependency Injection whereby we achieve different behaviors depending on what we inject.  C# purists don't like this idea but Typescript people do it all the time.