# Using a generic parameter on overloaded methods

Tags: c#, generics, methods, parameters

Why does this program output `Generic Value` and not `Hello world!`:

```
using System;

class Example
{
    public static void Print<T>(T value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Generic Value");
    }

    public static void Print(string value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }

    public static void GenericFunc<T>(T value)
    {
        Print(value);
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        GenericFunc("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

How is the generic method parameter being translated under the hood of C#?

Comment: Generic functions are only compiled once and any dispatch within them is based on the local type definitions. Inside `GenericFunc` there is only one overload of `Print` which applies so it will always be called.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Overload resolution is only done at compile-time.

Since `GenericFunc<T>` doesn't know whether `T` is a `string` or something else at compile-time, it can only ever use the `Print<T>(T value)` "overload".

Using `dynamic`, you can change this to a dynamic dispatch, and get the behaviour you expect:

```
Print((dynamic)value);
```

This makes the overload resolution happen at runtime, with the actual runtime type of `value`.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad Just keep in mind the *problems* you get from using `dynamic` as well, and you'll be fine :)

Comment: @Luaan but this one is classic case for using dynamic! right ? or is there anywork around to the above problem?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I've used it succesfully for exactly this kind of problem in the past, and it works great, yeah. Of course, it only works if you can afford it, there's plenty of cases where the overhead is non-trivial :) Of course, a more traditional OOP guy might tell you that it's very dirty, and you should create an adapter with a factory and... I'm not even going to continue. Let's just keep at "you can solve it using proper OOP as well". As far as I'm concerned, this is actually a pretty elegant solution to the problem :) Just be careful - `dynamic` is infectious.

Answer (score 0):

#### Simple answer to simple question

The other answer explains the way generic are bound (compile-time). But it doesn't answer on the OOP, good practice, or simply why you should never write this code in the first place.

**OOP**

The first O in OOP means Object and there is none with only static methods.

**Responsibility**

Let's think about the Generic versin of the method as a method responsible for printing a set of different possible types. `String` type is part of the set. So it should be managed by the generic version of your `Print` function.

```
public static void Print<T>(T value)
{
    Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
}
```

then you got the problem of nullity for ref types.

```
    public static void Print<T>(T value) where T : class
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(value.ToString());
        }
    }

    public static void GenericFunc<T>(T value) where T : class
    {
        Print(value);
    }
```

And for those who are aware of why you should not use dynamic unless in some cases ([see my anwer on that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859016/is-the-use-of-dynamic-considered-a-bad-practice/32817143#32817143)).

**More clean OOP solution**

Now imagine you have different objects to print. Each object should be responsible for knowing how to display it. Firstly, because it ease encapsulation of data by not leaking internal data to the external world. Secondly, because you've got an inherent coupling between the internal data and the printing function, so both should be located in the same place: inside the class. That's the purpose of the `ToString` function.

**Let's take some height...**

Now, we could imagine that it's not a Print function but something else.

We got a hierarchy of classes with overload on the same function (let's call it `Foo`) and a collection of instances from these classes for which you must call the function `Foo`. Let's then make all these classes implement the `IFooCallable` interface :

```
public interface IFooCallable
{
    void Foo();
}
```

**A little more complex...**

Ok, but imagine that there is not common way to process all these instances of classes because there are very different.

Let's call the [Visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). It's commonly used when you want to analyze some object tree with each node very different (like in [AST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree)).
It's a known pattern, making it easy to share knowledgable information with your team.

You got the **Visitor**:

```
public class Visitor : IVisitor
{
    public void Visit(Foo foo)
    {
        // do something with foo
    }

    public void Visit(Bar bar)
    {
        // do something with bar
    }
}
```

and the **Visitable**

```
public class Foo : IVisitable
{
    public void Accept(IVisitor visitor)
    {
        visitor.Visit(this);
    }
}
```

Moreover this pattern is reusable (you could write several implementation of IVisitor should you need to).

I don't buy the `dynamic` thing. Especially when there is more cleaner, faster alternative. If dynamic so great, why not writing this then ;)

```
    public static void Print(dynamic value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(value);            
    }

    public static void GenericFunc(dynamic value)
    {
        Print(value);
    }

    static void Main(dynamic[] args)
    {
        GenericFunc((dynamic)"Hello World");
    }
```