# generic resolution with dynamic cast failing in Unit Test

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, xunit

I'm working on a .NET Core 5 application. In some parts of the system, I'm using a cast to `dynamic` to handle generic type resolution. Something like this:

```
public void Foo(ISomething something){
    Bar((dynamic)something);
}

private void Bar<T>(T somethingElse) where T : ISomething
{ .... }
```

Works pretty well if I run the whole application. Now, for some mysterious reason, the same code refuses to work during Unit Tests. I get an exception as soon as it tries to call `Bar<T>()`, complaining that it's receiving an `object` instead of an `ISomething`.
I'm using XUnit.

Any idea?

**UPDATE 10/01/2021**
I've pushed the code [to GitHub](https://github.com/mizrael/OpenSleigh/commit/4683791e6be13bff99f9cac01c9ad6c56670b24b), the branch is [`coverage`](https://github.com/mizrael/OpenSleigh/tree/coverage).

[This is](https://github.com/mizrael/OpenSleigh/blob/coverage/tests/OpenSleigh.Persistence.InMemory.Tests/E2E/SimpleSagaScenario.cs#L16) the failing test. The issue happens on [this line](https://github.com/mizrael/OpenSleigh/blob/coverage/src/OpenSleigh.Persistence.InMemory/Messaging/InMemoryPublisher.cs#L24) in the `InMemoryPublisher` class, when casting the message to dynamic.

Comment: You can’t use dynamic with generics like that. Generally speaking you should avoid using `dynamic` entirely. `dynamic` is its own *static-type* which does not implement interfaces.

Comment: Is there a reason you don’t just pass `something` directly into `Bar` without casting to `dynamic`? Also note that “resolution” is the wrong term: overloads are _resolved_, but generics are _instantiated_.

Comment: it works pretty well at runtime, as noted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35340243/3279163

Comment: I agree with you when it comes to avoiding `dynamic` as much as possible, but to be fair I don't think I have many choices here. Internally I have to call generic methods on other classes and I need the concrete type from `something`, not the interface.

Comment: Does this not work ? `Foo<T>(T something) where T : ISomething { Bar(something) }`

Comment: I cant change Foo, it has to take the interface as parameter. But the issue here is NOT with the design. I want to understand why this thing works normally and fails only during tests

Comment: You will need a [mcve] of both it working and it not working.

Comment: Are your tests running under .NET 5 - or .NET Core 1,2,3, or even .NET Framework? .NET 5 introduced some major changes to the CLR and you may have stumbled across an undocumented breaking-change. As the others have said **we need a minimum reproducible example** - do you have a git repo I can clone?

Comment: Sure. I'll push everything tomorrow and let you know. It's .NET 5, btw. Thanks!

Comment: I've updated the question and added more details. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found the issue. I had marked the `ISomething` implementations as `internal`. Switching to `public` fixed it.