# How to Convert Anonymous Type to List <dynamic> using Linq to SQL in C#

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

I'm new to C# and Linq.

Actually, I want to return anonymous types into list. anonymous types is contain of List, String, and DateTime. I tried with the code as below but its giving an error. please help and tell me what I am missing or suggest how can I achieve this.

//Error:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid..
```

//Edited C# Linq Code

```
        public List<AuditInfo> GetScanAudit(object Id, DateTime? fromTime, DateTime? toTime, string type = null,
            string user = null, Pager pager = null)
        {
            using (var ctx = new PlantDataContext())
            {
                var query = from audit in ctx.AuditLog
                            join ent in ctx.Scans on audit.RecordId equals ent.Id.ToString() into audits
                            from entaudits in audits.DefaultIfEmpty()
                            where audit.TypeFullName == "ABCD.DB.Model.Scan"
                            select new
                            {
                                audit,
                                entaudits
                            };

                if (Id != null)
                {
                    query = query.Where(x => x.audit.RecordId == Id.ToString());
                }
                if (fromTime.HasValue)
                {
                    var tmp = new DateTimeOffset(fromTime.Value.ToUniversalTime());
                    query = query.Where(x => x.audit.EventDateUTC >= tmp);
                }
                if (toTime.HasValue)
                {
                    var tmp = new DateTimeOffset(toTime.Value.ToUniversalTime());
                    query = query.Where(x => x.audit.EventDateUTC <= tmp);
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(type))
                {
                    var parseEvent = (EventType)Enum.Parse(typeof(EventType), type);
                    query = query.Where(x => x.audit.EventType == parseEvent);
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(user))
                {
                    query = query.Where(x => x.audit.UserName == user);
                }
                if (pager != null)
                {
                    var totalRecords = query.Count();
                    pager.TotalRecords = totalRecords;
                    var data = query.Select(x =>
                        new AuditInfo
                        {
                            x.audit.TypeFullName, //Here Error Occurs
                            x.audit.UserName,//Here Error Occurs
                            x.audit.EventType,//Here Error Occurs
                            x.audit.EventDateUTC,//Here Error Occurs
                            @LogDetails = x.audit.LogDetails.ToList(), //Here Error Occurs
                            x.entaudits.Name,
                            @Description = x.entaudits.Description
                        })
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.EventDateUTC)
                        .Skip(pager.From)
                        .Take(pager.PageSize);
                    try
                    {
                        var list1 = data.ToList<AuditInfo>();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                    }
                    var list = data.ToList<AuditInfo>();
                    pager.RecordCount = list.Count;
                    return list;
                }
                else
                {
                    var list = query.Select(x =>
                        new AuditInfo
                        {
                            x.audit.TypeFullName,
                            x.audit.UserName,
                            x.audit.EventType,
                            x.audit.EventDateUTC,
                            @LogDetails = x.audit.LogDetails.ToList(),
                            x.entaudits.Name,
                            @Description = x.entaudits.Description
                        })
                            .OrderByDescending(x => x.EventDateUTC)
                        .ToList<AuditInfo>();
                    return list;
                }
            }
        }
```

When I debug the code totalRecords variable showing count 6, but is showing exception with message Specified cast is not valid at this line var list1 = data.ToList();

Comment: Not really sure the `sql` tag is relevant here

Comment: @CaiusJard, seems like OP wants us to convert from Linq to SQL.

Comment: Change your method's return type to something else: a strongly type class, or C#7 value tuples.

Comment: where do you want to use this method => `GetScanAudit` and why you choose return type `List<dynamic>` and why not `List<SomeClass>`?

Comment: You can use `.OrderByDescending(x => x.EventDateUTC).Cast<dynamic>().ToList()`.

Comment: @jarlh i'm really not seeing it.. I parse the title as "Linq-to-SQL", a defunct data access technology and probably misapplied here, rather than "help  me convert this linq into the equivalent sql" .. but i could be wrong

Comment: does it also throw an error when you do data.ToList();?

Comment: What is the point to return dynamic? C# is a strongly typed programming language and there is no need for your case to return List of dynamic. If you are new to C# you should know that strong types are good, while you should avoid dynamic.

Comment: Why dynamic is bad https://stackoverflow.com/a/32817143/1099716

Comment: @S.Akbari I am trying with Tuple, I'm searching for example but not found a sample.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tuples

Comment: @ershoaib I want to use this list in view model. I don't know how to use anonymous type with Class list. please suggest me how to go for that.

Comment: @AmanB yes sir same error throws at  ToList();

Comment: @SandyN, I added my answer below :)

Comment: @AccessDenied Strong types? please suggest any example. sir

Comment: There is below by ershoaib

Comment: @ershoaib Ok sir.. I will try it.

Comment: @SandyN the problem is that there is a mismatching type in your paging query, not with converting anonymous type to dynamic. Start commenting the variables one by one and you'll find the culprit

Comment: @AmanB Yes sir, `x.audit.EventDateUTC,
                            @LogDetails = x.audit.LogDetails.ToList(),`
 these are culprit
only for these its throwing error

Comment: @SandyN Is EventDateUTC same type in the code and database?

Comment: [EventDateUTC] as DateTimeoffset in code and in DB DateTime. well if I can  comment this EventDateUTC   but still there is LogDetails.ToList()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use strongly return type for your method like `List<ClassName>` instead of `List<dynamic>`

```
public List<ClassName> GetScanAudit(object Id, DateTime? fromTime, DateTime? toTime, string type = null, string user = null, Pager pager = null)
{
   ...
}
```

Then your query will be

```
var data = query.Select(x =>
                new ClassName
                {
                    TypeFullName = x.audit.TypeFullName,
                    UserName = x.audit.UserName,
                    EventType = x.audit.EventType,
                    EventDateUTC = x.audit.EventDateUTC,
                    LogDetails = x.audit.LogDetails.ToList(),
                    Name = x.entaudits.Name,
                    Description = x.entaudits.Description
                })
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.EventDateUTC)
                .Skip(pager.From)
                .Take(pager.PageSize);

var list = data.ToList<ClassName>();
```

And your strongly type class look like

```
public class ClassName
{
    public string TypeFullName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string EventType { get; set; }
    public DateTime EventDateUTC { get; set; }
    public List<LogDetail> LogDetails { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Make sure the datatype of each property should match in your `.Select` clause in query

**Edit:**

```
if (pager != null)
            {
                var totalRecords = query.Count();
                pager.TotalRecords = totalRecords;
                var data = query.Select(x =>
                    new AuditInfo
                    {
                        TypeFullName = x.audit.TypeFullName,
                        UserName = x.audit.UserName,
                        EventType = x.audit.EventType,
                        EventDateUTC = x.audit.EventDateUTC,
                        LogDetails = x.audit.LogDetails.ToList(),
                        Name = x.entaudits.Name,
                        Description = x.entaudits.Description
                    })
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.EventDateUTC)
                    .Skip(pager.From)
                    .Take(pager.PageSize);
                try
                {
                    var list1 = data.ToList<AuditInfo>();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                }
                var list = data.ToList<AuditInfo>();
                pager.RecordCount = list.Count;
                return list;
            }
            else
            {
                var list = query.Select(x =>
                    new AuditInfo
                    {
                        TypeFullName = x.audit.TypeFullName,
                        UserName = x.audit.UserName,
                        EventType = x.audit.EventType,
                        EventDateUTC = x.audit.EventDateUTC,
                        LogDetails = x.audit.LogDetails.ToList(),
                        Name = x.entaudits.Name,
                        Description = x.entaudits.Description
                    })
                        .OrderByDescending(x => x.EventDateUTC)
                    .ToList<AuditInfo>();
                return list;
            }
```

Comment: Thank you sir I will try this one.

Comment: @SandyN, let me know if it help or not?

Comment: Sure sir. I will do.

Comment: make sure that => if you `x.audit.TypeFullName` is string then in class `TypeFullName` will be string and if `x.audit.EventDateUTC` is `DateTime` then in class `EventDateUTC` is `DateTime` means you must assign proper datatype to class property that should match in your select clause query

Comment: Yes sir I created another Class file for that

Comment: Error occurs at `data` 
`IQueryable<<anonymous type: string TypeFullName, string UserName, EventType EventType, DateTime EventDateUTC, List<AuditLogDetail> LogDetails, string Name, string Description>>' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and the best extension method overload 'Enumerable.ToList<AuditInfo>(IEnumerable<AuditInfo>)' requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable<AuditInfo>`

Comment: you have to write `x =>
                new ClassName {}` to all of your method i think you have still `x =>
                new {}` somewhere else

Comment: use `x => new ClassName {}` though out  your method make sure no one `x => new {}` remaining

Comment: also verify that all the `ToList` contains `ClassName` instead of `dynamic` no any `ToList` contains `dynamic` all should be `ToList<ClassName>();`

Comment: Yes gone.. and another error occurs.. 
`Invalid initializer member declarator` at
  ` x.audit.TypeFullName,
                            x.audit.UserName,
                            x.audit.EventType,
                            x.audit.EventDateUTC,
                            @LogDetails = x.audit.LogDetails.ToList(),
                            x.entaudits.Name,`

Comment: use like this where error occures => `TypeFullName = x.audit.TypeFullName,
                            UserName = x.audit.UserName,
                            EventType = x.audit.EventType,
                            EventDateUTC = x.audit.EventDateUTC,
                            LogDetails = x.audit.LogDetails.ToList(),
                            Name = x.entaudits.Name,
                            Description = x.entaudits.Description`

Comment: means you need to specify left hand side member in your class to get values from query

Comment: the whole code we cannot post here.. character limitation here. 
yes sir. this error is gone and another occurring.

Comment: add your latest code in your question with **Edit:** heading and tell me the new error?

Comment: Edited Please check the question

Comment: just assign like `TypeFullName = x.audit.TypeFullName` for all of select clause in all the queries so error will be gone

Comment: see the **Edit:** section in answer for your reference i assign `TypeFullName = x.audit.TypeFullName` like for all properties

Comment: yes that erros gone. and but this one `  ret = GetUserAudit(Id, fromTime, toTime, type, user, pager);'  //Here Error Occurs

Answer (score 9):

You have to cast the anonymous objects to dynamic.

To do this with linq you can use `Cast<dynamic>` linq method:

```
var list = query.Select(x =>
    new
    {
        x.audit.TypeFullName,
        x.audit.UserName,
        x.audit.EventType,
        x.audit.EventDateUTC,
        @LogDetails = x.audit.LogDetails.ToList(),
        x.entaudits.Name,
        @Description = x.entaudits.Description
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.EventDateUTC)
    .AsEnumerable()
    .Cast<dynamic>()
    .ToList<dynamic>(); \\ here exception occures
return list;
```

Comment: Not working sir. 
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Unable to cast the type 'Anonymous type' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types. occurred

Comment: @SandyN you can use `.AsEnumerable()` instead of `.Cast<dynamic>`.

Comment: still not working sir,
`An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: Specified cast is not valid. occurred`

Comment: Using `AsEnumerable()` and `Cast<dynamic>()` works for me

Comment: Works great! Thanks