# How to create a delegate for a generic method that requires casting back and forth

Tags: c#, generics, casting, delegates

I have a method:

```
MyMethod<T>(T) where T: struct, MyInterface
```

I have a target delegate as:

```
public delegate void MyDelegate(object myObject)
```

I have a collection of Types that are both structs and implement `MyInterface`

So invoking `MyMethod` is as simple as:

```
myMethodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(myType).Invoke(target, new object[]{myObject})
```

that is, because `Invoke` accepts `object` and does the casting for me somewhere in the internal code.

The issue is that I can't seem to make a delegate like `MyDelegate(object)` because object is not `struct, MyInterface`

I get why

```
(MyDelegate)addComponentData.MakeGenericMethod(MyType).CreateDelegate(typeof(MyDelegate), target)
```

does not work, but I have no idea how to solve it

**The reason I need this** is because every time I am using any of these objects, I am using them as MyInterface, I have no idea which type they are, only that they implement MyInterface and are structs, therefore they are eligible for the method I need to invoke them on.
To make all of this reflection faster, I want to use CreateDelegate, as it seems it is only twice as slow as an actual normal invocation of the method where MethodInfo.Invoke is 100 times slower (source: [Is the use of dynamic considered a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859016/is-the-use-of-dynamic-considered-a-bad-practice/32817143#32817143))

Comment: Interesting question but why is it a requirement to do all this through reflection?

Comment: because the list of types is created at runtime using runtime code compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make wrapper method that takes an object and use it to construct delegate:

```
public void Wrapper<T>(object s) where T : struct, MyInterface
{
    MyMethod<T>((T)s);
}
```

Comment: the wrapper method will inevitably have to use Invoke, which is 100 times slower than CreateDelegate. If I were to do this, I would just use Invoke

Comment: It's calling `Invoke` on the delegate that points to `Wrapper<T>`, not a `MethodInfo`. Big difference.

Comment: @Guedez ? why can't you use the same code you had in the question like  - `(MyDelegate)methodInfoForWrapper.MakeGenericMethod(MyType).CreateDelegate(typeof(MyDelegate), target)` to create delegate? I'm clearly missed something from your question then - consider to edit the question to clarify restrictions.

Comment: After some preliminary checks, it seems to be working, I will finish some more tests and mark as the answer

Comment: Worked like a charm, funny how a solution so simple slipped past my mind for so long

Answer (score 0):

The only point of using a `struct` generic method constraint is to avoid boxing.  You aren't avoiding boxing.  So just declare the method as:

```
MyMethod(MyInterface obj)
```

Comment: It's not my method, it's from a library