# C# change variable type in switch or other way to move around it

Tags: c#

I have a problem with `switch`. The user can select one of few options. Then based on the user's choice, I have to change a variable type.

```
var train = new Propagation();

switch (alghoritm)
{
    case 1:
       train = OtherPropagation();
    case 2:
       train = OtherPropagation2();
    case 3:
       train = OtherPropagation3();
    default:
       train = Propagation();
}
```

C# has static variable types, so it's impossible for me to change it, but based on choice, the rest code works diffrently.

Do you have any ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try dynamic data type.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic

Comment: How is this helpful for the code that happens after the switch?

Comment: The `dynamic` keyword should be avoided.  Is the use of dynamic considered a bad practice? - Stack Overflow - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859016/is-the-use-of-dynamic-considered-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 3):

You can create a common interface for all theses types (that calls to `OtherPropagation`, `OtherPropagation2` return). Then you can use this common interface as the type of `train`.

E.g. Let's call this `IPropagation`

```
public interface IPropagation
{
    // place here the common methods
}
```

Then change the return type of your methods, `OtherPropagation`, `OtherPropagation2` etc. to be of `IPropagation`. Furthermore, you have to implement this interface for all the types that currently these methods return.

Last, change the type of variable `train` to be of `IPropagation`.

Answer (score 1):

if `Propagation` is base class of others, this works:

```
class Propagation { }
class Propagation1 : Propagation  { }
class Propagation2 : Propagation  { }
class Propagation3 : Propagation  { }


Propagation GetPropagation(int alghoritm)  //return base class
{
    Propagation train;
    switch (alghoritm)
    {
    case 1:
     train = Propagation1();
    case 2:
     train = Propagation2();
    case 3:
     train = Propagation3();
    default:
     train = Propagation();
    }
     return train;
}
```

if all classes have a common interface `IPropagation`, then this works:

```
class Propagation : IPropagation { }
class Propagation1 : IPropagation  { }
class Propagation2 : IPropagation  { }
class Propagation3 : IPropagation  { }

IPropagation GetPropagation(int alghoritm)  //return interface
{
    IPropagation train;
    switch (alghoritm)
    {
    case 1:
     train = Propagation1();
    case 2:
     train = Propagation2();
    case 3:
     train = Propagation3();
    default:
     train = Propagation();
    }
     return train;
}
```