# DelegateMethod to improve Reflection on set of Objects

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a situation where I have a very large list of objects for which I want to call a user-defined list of methods (it's for building a generic report of the list of objects).
The method signature is provided as MethodInfo (via reflection). Right now, I use method.Invoke to call this method for all of my individual objects to retrieve the individual values of my objects.

Something along those lines:

```
private void writeReport (List<object> rows, MethodInfo[] columns, string dest){
   System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(dest);

   StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
   foreach(object row in rows){
      foreach(MethodInfo m in columns){
         builder.Append(m.Invoke(row).ToString());
      }
      writer.WriteLine(builder.ToString());
      builder.Clear();
   }

   writer.Close();
}
```

Note: This is just a dummy method to get an idea of my framework. There are obviously things missing like a header or separator signs etc.

I read about DelegateReflection and how much faster it is to the regular reflection Invoke call but the examples I found never have to call the same method on different objects. It's always a static method rather then a member method of an object.

Is there any other way how I can make this faster?
Note that my list of "rows" can easily contain > 10'000'000 elements.

ALSO NOTE:
I have seen this post
[MethodInfo.Invoke performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10313979/methodinfo-invoke-performance-issue)

However, I was wondering whether something better has come up since (also empirically trying this suggestion did not yield any performance gain).

Comment: What are the actual types contained within `rows`? Can you define an `interface` for those object types to implement instead?

Comment: Also, your code seems dangerous - what happens if someone pipes-in an object with a method named `String FireZeMissiles()` which returns a `String` report of [megadeaths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megadeath) (and not simply `"I am le tired"`)?

Comment: Can you make some example to show what is writeReport paramter input?

Comment: Yes, we absolutely can look at delegates for this; however, it would be much simpler and more efficient to *not use `MethodInfo` in the first place* - there are much better APIs, such as just a `Func<object,object>` (although we can do better than that) - is it possible to change the API at all?

Comment: also: it is kinda awkward dealing in `object`; a generic `WriteReport<T>` that took a `List<T>` i.e. elements of the correct input type `T`  would be great

Comment: finally: what are the signatures of the `MethodInfo` here? presumably they are instance methods on a particular `T`, but: do they return `object`? can they return something else, i.e. `string` etc? and they are always parameterless?

Comment: Consider this to be a framework that can export fields of any list of objects by crawling through methods that follow a certain signature (no parameter and any output one can call "ToString" on).

The user is first presented with a list of all the methods that follow this signature (where he can select which ones he is interested) and then calls the export method on this list of objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, personally I'd change the API to use generics and delegates *in the API*:

```cs
    private void WriteReport<T>(List<T> rows, Func<T, string>[] columns, string dest)
    {
        using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(dest))
        {
            foreach (T row in rows)
            {
                foreach (var m in columns)
                {
                    writer.Write(m(row));
                }
                writer.WriteLine();
                writer.Flush();
            }
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
```

Then you can just use lambdas at the call site, i.e.

```cs
List<Foo> foos = ...
yourObject.writeReport(foos, new[] { x => x.SomeMethod(), x => x.AnotherMethod() }, path);
```

---

However, if that isn't possible, then: something like the following should work nicely:

```cs
    static readonly ParameterExpression s_sharedParam = Expression.Parameter(
        typeof(object), "obj");
    static readonly ParameterExpression[] s_sharedParams = new[] { s_sharedParam };
    static Func<object,object> AsFuncObjectObject(MethodInfo method)
    {
        Expression body = Expression.Call(
            Expression.Convert(s_sharedParam, method.DeclaringType), method);
        if (method.ReturnType.IsValueType) // manually box
            body = Expression.Convert(body, typeof(object));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<object, object>>(body, s_sharedParams).Compile();
    }

    private void writeReport(List<object> rows, MethodInfo[] columns, string dest)
    {
        using (var writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(dest))
        {
            var delegates = Array.ConvertAll(columns, col => AsFuncObjectObject(col));
            foreach (object row in rows)
            {
                foreach (var m in delegates)
                {
                    writer.Write(m(row).ToString());
                }
                writer.WriteLine();
                writer.Flush();
            }
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
```

---

Note: the use of `Expression` here is to deal with the ambiguity of the method signature, and the lack of generics. If the input type is well known as a `T`, and the return type is known (presumably either `string` or `object`), then you can use `Delegate.CreateDelegate` directly, simply specifying `null` as the target object. `Delegate.CreateDelegate` allows a special usage where if you pass in a `null` target as the target instance of an instance method, **and** you specify a delegate type with one-too-many parameters, then it treats the first parameter as the per-call target instance. So; if you are dealing with generic `T` and `string`, you could use simply:

```cs
private void WriteReport<T>(List<T> rows, MethodInfo[] columns, string dest)
{
    // ...
    var delegates = Array.ConvertAll(columns,
        col => (Func<T, string>)Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, string>), col));
    foreach (T row in rows)
    {
        foreach (var m in delegates)
        {
            writer.Write(m(row));
    // ...
```

Comment: That last part about the "special usage" of the CreateDelegate was EXACTLY what I was looking for :).